# Displaying labels with different names on Blogger. Is that possible?

Tags: label, blogger

I'm trying to figure out labels on Blogger.

I want to use labels as categories on my blog like everyone.

But the big problem is, my category names contains Turkish, Latin-Extended characters like this: "Çiçekler ve Doğa".

For example, my category address is: ...blogspot.com/search/label/cicekler_ve_doga

When my visitors click this link and go to this category, they see a message on page like this:

"Showing posts with label cicekler_ve_doga."

I want to display a different message to my visitors instead of this. For example:

"You are in ÇİÇEKLER ve DOĞA category right now."

So, I want to display a label name differently to my visitors.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible, try this code

```
<p>your are in <b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == "cicekler_ve_doga"'>ÇİÇEKLER ve DOĞA</b:if>.</p>
```